# Html div class link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok with my div class I want the example text to link to another page. How would I do that? and also I want the video background to click to another page. Any help?

```
 <div class="container">
        <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
            <source src="Burning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="Burning.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <div class="text">Example</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: 'I want the video background to click to another page'. Do you mean you want the user to be redirected when he clicks the background?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at the problem? Or at least an example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes i want that user to click the background and be redirected to another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment my best guess is that you want this:

```
<div class="container" >
    <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop id="video">
        <source src="Burning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="Burning.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="text"><a href="page2">Example</a></div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", redirect);

function redirect(){
    window.location.replace("page1")
}
</script>
```